# Change lowercase to uppercase in transactional emails

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm very new to all this but I'm still learning even after 50! Maybe one day I know it all! ;-) I'm looking at the transactional emails and want to make some changes on the following code: See bold

**`<b>{{var vendor.vendor_id}}</b>`** The outcome of this is the vendor_name but this is lower case. How can I make the outcome uppercase?

**`<a href="mailto:{{var vendor.email}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;">{{var vendor.email}}</a>`** The outcome of this is the vendor email address but how to hide this url and have this replaced by just **Email Us**

**`<a href="{{var homepage}}">{{var homepage}}</a>`**. Also here the outcome is a long URL of the vendor store but would like to replace this with the vendor name only. So the url should be hidden and show **Vendor** only

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For

1)

```
<b style="text-transform:uppercase">{{var vendor.vendor_id}}</b>
```

2)

```
<a href="mailto:{{var vendor.email}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;">Email Us</a>
```

3)

```
<a href="{{var homepage}}">{{var vendor.vendor_id}}</a>
```

For 3 i have assume you have vendor { vendor_id  } as column in database just like email to display vendor name in Transnational email.

hope all 3 solution will work for you.

Comment: @tee3sports,hope this help.don't forget to acpt so some one can use it for future used

Comment: Sure, but how to I do acpt?

Comment: @tee3sports, on left side of my answer there is correct mark below down Arrow. just click on correct mark.